# Magento 2.3.5 admin panel showing blank page

Tags: magento2, admin, frontend

[image]

After successful installation when you open admin url, Admin panel showing black and also frontend links not working.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Magento installation root folder.
2. Then lib->internal->Magento->Framework->View->Element->Template->File->Validator.php
3. Go to line no 140 and replace the below code

**From**

```
If(0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
            return true;
            }
```

**To**

```
$realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
            if ($realDirectory && 0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
            return true;
            }
```

Then reload the page admin and frontend issue will resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Open `Validator.php` file from below path

```
vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php
```

Go to line number **140**

Replace below code

```
If(0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
    return true;
}
```

with below code

```
$realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
if ($realDirectory && 0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
    return true;
}
```